An interesting family of seminorms $\mathcal F$ and comparison between the topology generated by this seminorms and the Weak Operator Topology.
I am learning functional analysis and I am stuck with the following questions from Strong Operator Topology and Weak Operator topology on $\mathcal B(H)=\{T:H\to H:T$ is Op-Norm continuous,linear $\}$.
Problem
Let $\mathcal F=\{\|\bullet\|_{\eta,\zeta}:$ $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (\|\zeta_k\|^2+\|\eta_k\|^2)<+\infty$ where $\|\varphi\|_{\eta,\zeta}=|\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\langle \bullet \zeta_n,\eta_n\rangle\}|$which is a separating family of seminorms on $\mathcal B(H)$.I am supposed to show that if $\tau$ is the topology generated by the separating family $\mathcal F$,then $\tau$ is strictly finer than the Weak Operator Topology on $\mathcal B(H)$.
I do not have a strong background of weak and strong operator topologies,can someone provide me with a guidance to solve this problem?

This is known as the $\sigma$-weak, ultraweak, or weak$^\ast$ topology on $B(H)$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_topologies. General hint: the linear functional $T \mapsto \sum_n \langle T \zeta_n, \eta_n \rangle$ is going to be continuous under this topology, but unless the sum can be reduced to a finite sum, it is not continuous under the weak operator topology.

A slightly more specific hint: let ${e_n}$ be an ONB of $H$. Then choose $\zeta_n = \eta_n = 2^{-n}e_n$.

If you have vectors $\eta,\zeta\in H$, you can consider the families
$$
\tilde\eta=(\eta,0,0,\ldots),\qquad\qquad \tilde\zeta=(\zeta,0,0,\ldots). 
$$
Then the seminorm $\|\cdot\|_{\tilde\eta,\tilde\zeta}$ in $\mathcal F$ agrees with the seminorm $\|\cdot\|_{\eta,\zeta}=|\langle\,\cdot\,\eta,\zeta\rangle|$. This shows that every seminorm for the weak operator topology belong to $\mathcal F$, and hence the topology induced by $\mathcal F$ is stronger than the weak operator topology.
